# Почему не запускается проект на React Native?

Tags: react-native

Решил поработать с React Native, но начались проблемы.
Устанавливал все как на офиц. сайте

Но при попытке запустить проект мне выдает ошибку: "Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?" и по каким то причинам в проекте не появляется папка node_modules, а при попытке сделать npm install ( с yarn тоже самое) происходит ошибка.

Я удалял yarn, переустанавливал expo-cli, пробовал инициализировать новые проекты через npm, делал запуски через все возможные команды expo start, npm start, yarn start, даже node.js обновил, но ничего не помогло :(

Почему ничего не работает и как запустить проект?

Answer (score 0):

Измени версию expo на новую или обновляй.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618967/unable-to-find-expo-in-this-project-have-you-run-yarn-npm-install-yet

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Я это уже делал, оно все равно не запускается